# Programatically intercept and/or manipulate check-in comments in TFS / Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, version-control, tfs

is there a way to intercept a check-in comment during check-in operation on Team Foundation Server Version Control in order to enrich it with additional information?

Another option would be to intercept it and ensure that it's formatted correctly and contain some mandatory information.

We have some policy regarding formatting comments and I would like to add some prevention / user assistance functionality at that point.

The worst case would be a shortcut to fill out the comment field in Visual Studio from some predefined template.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need here is a custom check-in policy. [Power Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb980963) has some policies out of the box, however they do not cover your needs. The closest one requires users to provide a meaningful comment for their check-ins, which is not what you are looking for.

Still there is a way to implement policy on your own. Here is the [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jimlamb/archive/2010/03/31/how-to-implement-package-and-deploy-custom-check-in-policy-for-tfs-2010.aspx) on MSDN written by Jim Lamb. He explains how one can implement custom check-in policy, package it and deploy on TFS 2010.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I looked at interfaces and it seems that using custom policy you can validate the check-in comment and reject it showing up the reason of rejection. This is my minimal requirement, but I have not found any way to adjust the comment. Am I missing something or there is no way to do so?

Comment: It seems that this is the max you can achieve using policies. However, you might want to check out other ways to extend the TFS Version Control. Here is the [starting point](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb130331.aspx). In particular take a look at `ChangeSummary` [class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.client.changesetsummary.aspx). Inheriting from it and applying necessary template to the comment might be the way